# While loop going through once more than expected [python]

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import random as rd

secret_number = rd.randint(1,100)
num_guesses = 5
guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))


while num_guesses > 0 and guess != secret_number:
    if guess > secret_number:
        print(f"Too high.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
        guess = int(input("Make a guess."))
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print(f"Too low.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
        guess = int(input("Make a guess."))
    else:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
```

I would expect the while loop to go through a maximum of 5 times, but it seems to be going through 6 times.  Can someone please explain like I'm five why that's happening?

I get the following output.  You can see I've guessed six times (50,40,50,30,10,10).

```
Please guess a number>? 50
Too low.
 You have 4 guesses remaining.
Make a guess.>? 40
Too low.
 You have 3 guesses remaining.
Make a guess.>? 50
Too low.
 You have 2 guesses remaining.
Make a guess.>? 30
Too low.
 You have 1 guesses remaining.
Make a guess.>? 10
Too low.
 You have 0 guesses remaining.
Make a guess.>? 10
```

Comment: Please post your real code. The code you have shown should result in an error something about `guess` not being defined.

Comment: Apologies, just edited.

Comment: Its because you have these lines: `num_guesses = num_guesses - 1; guess = int(input("Make a guess."))`. You decrease the counter, but also ask for a new guess without checking the counter first.

Comment: When I try the code (and repeatedly try a wrong guess), I get 5 prompts from the loop. I don't see an issue. If you were expected to be prompted 5 times *in total*, just to make sure, you understand that the first prompt you have is *outside the loop*, so it won't count against that limit?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @quamrana suggested; you need to check `num_guesses > 0` before asking using again:

```
import random as rd

secret_number = rd.randint(1,100)
num_guesses = 5
guess = int(input("Please guess a number"))


while num_guesses> 0 and guess != secret_number:
    if guess > secret_number:
        print(f"Too high.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
        if num_guesses > 0:
            guess = int(input("Make a guess."))
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print(f"Too low.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
        if num_guesses > 0:
            guess = int(input("Make a guess."))
    else:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
```

---

Edit: As suggested by @Abdul you can just keep one input after the while loop:

```
import random as rd

secret_number = rd.randint(1,100)
num_guesses = 5
guess = 0        # a place holder value and it will not be equal to secret_number as it goes from 1 to 100

while num_guesses> 0 and guess != secret_number:
    guess = int(input("Make a guess."))
    if guess > secret_number:
        print(f"Too high.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print(f"Too low.\n You have {num_guesses - 1} guesses remaining.")
        num_guesses = num_guesses - 1
    else:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
```

Comment: Better yet, just remove the input for the guess before the loop, remove the ones inside the if / elif conditions as well and just add one at the start of the loop.

Comment: Thank you both @AbdulAzizBarkat and Goku (would tag both but it will only let me tag one of you).  Both versions work.  I tend to prefer Abdul's because it is a little more straightforward.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat don't you need to define 'guess' outside the loop (even just giving it a placeholder value)?  Otherwise you will get a NameError when the while loop starts.

Comment: @TimStarr not really, the first line in the loop is assigning a value to that variable, why would you get a name error then?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat because it is part of the while statement, how can it know to start the while loop if 'guess' is not defined before the loop?  Is python able to do that?